# Select the maximum of top 3 values in ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `Orders` and a column named `Shipping Cost`. I have to get the distinct three minimum values of `Shipping Cost` and find the maximum value out of those three. I can get the three values in ascending order but I don't know how to find the maximum value.

This is how I did it:

`select distinct top 3 [Shipping Cost] from Orders order by [Shipping Cost] asc;`

It looks like:

```
Shipping Cost
 0.00
 4.00
 5.00
```

I need to get the `5.00` only.
Thank you for your attention.

Edit: I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What DB are you using? I assume MS SQL Server from your query...

Comment: Which version of sql server?

Comment: Try to use MAX() function instead. select MAX([Shipping Cost]) from Orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested `SELECT` clause for this:

```
SELECT MAX([Shipping Cost]) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 [Shipping Cost]
    FROM Orders
    ORDER BY [Shipping Cost] ASC
) Top3Orders;
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008 you can use a subquery with `dense_rank`:

```
select distinct [Shipping Cost]
from   (select dense_rank() over (order by [Shipping Cost]) as r, * 
        from Orders) as Orders 
where  r = 3
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/GNM49350)

If you are on SQL Server 2012 or more recent, then:

```
select   distinct [Shipping Cost] 
from     Orders 
order by [Shipping Cost] asc
offset   2 rows
fetch    next 1 row only;
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/TLO56737)

Comment: I added a version for SQL Server 2008 in case your version does not support it.